# Query String redirect with complex query

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm moving an 'add-on' CRM from one CMS to another. There are a fair amount of personal pages on this CRM and I'm trying to set up a redirect so the old URL redirects to the new CMS site.

I've tried a few different variations of a query string rewrite with no success. I think it's due to the complexity of my query and could use some help.

The old URL:
mysite.org/subdira/index.php/component/civicrm/?task=civicrm/pcp/info&reset=1&id=20

new URL:
mysite.org/subdirb/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/pcp/info&reset=1&id=20

The code I have in now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/subdira/index\.php/component/civicrm/$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^task=civicrm/pcp/info&reset=1&id=([0-9]*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.org/subdirb/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/pcp/info&reset=1&id=%1 [R=302,L]
```

is not working, ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Place this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^task=civicrm/pcp/info&reset=1&id=[0-9]+$ 
RewriteRule ^subdira/index\.php/component/civicrm/?$ /subdirb/?page=CiviCRM [R=302,L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: No dice using this redirect.

Comment: What full URL did you use for testing? What is location of this .htaccess? Is there `/subdira/.htaccess` as well?

Comment: I used the following:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^task=civicrm/pcp/info&reset=1&id=[0-9]+$ 
RewriteRule ^ subdira/index\.php/component/civicrm/?$ /subdirb/?page=CiviCRM [R=302,L,QSA,NC]

The .htaccess file is in the top directory. Yes, there is an .htacess file in subdira - it is a Joomla install so I assume it is the usual writeup the comes with a joomla install.

Am I missing something in the rewrite rule? should there be more after '/subdirb/?page=CiviCRM'? (This is a wordpress install).

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit your question and provide it there.